# Неправильно вычисляется сумма

Tags: pascal, for, pascalabc.net

В общем, моя программа должна посчитать сумму в цикле for. Она вроде делает это, но получается, что, неправильно. Что может быть не так?

[image: Формула]

Вывод:

```
37.429935
```

Ожидаемый ответ:

```
181.704652
```

Код программы:

```
var U : real;

begin
    for var x:=1 to 10 do 
    begin
        U := sqrt(1 + power(x,3) + (4*power(x,2)));
    end;
    write('U = ', U:0:6);
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы не суммируете результат предыдущей итерации `U := U + выражение`.

```
var U : real;

begin
    for var x:=1 to 10 do 
    begin
        U := U + sqrt(1 + power(x,3) + (4*power(x,2)));
    end;
    write('U = ', U:0:6);
end.
```

Comment: Да, спасибо за подсказку! Обязательно отмечу Ваш ответ, как решение)